# PyQt5 Reading Image from a Different Color Space

Tags: python, pyqt5, color-space

Let a numpy 3 dimensional array that represents an image be given. It is mentionned in other posts how to display such an image PyQt5 . However, this time, the given image has a colorspace of YBR_Full . The usual way of dealing with this is by using the command `convert_color_space`. But such a command would make my code run too slow in case I have a large amount of images to display. My question is: is there any way to make PyQt5 window to read and display directly images of the color space YBR_Full (and more generally color spaces other than RGB ) so that we do NOT need to convert any image to other color space ? That is, is it possible for me to change the default color space used by `PyQt5` ?

Appendix:
YBR_Full stands for Y, Cb, and Cr. The conversion formula is given by:
[image]

Comment: QImage doesn't support YUV, so there's no direct way to show that data, you have to do a per-pixel conversion with the inverted formula and use [`setPixel()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#setPixel).